# 0580/42/M/J/21 IGCSE Question clarification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There was a 4 mark question on this paper that had me stumped. I don't remember it very clearly, but it was either:

$3^{2y-x} = \frac{1}{9^x} \cdot 3^{2x-1}$

OR

$3^{2y-x} \cdot \frac{1}{9^x} = 3^{2x-1}$

Express $y$ in terms of $x$.

I think the solution has something to do with equalizing the bases by some method requiring mixing and matching the rules of indices but I'm not entirely sure. I have no other ideas on how I can derive a variable in the exponents besides getting the bases to match.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not related to "linear-algebra" !

Comment: Take the $\log_3$ of everything.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use useful titles. "0580/42/M/J/21 IGCSE"? Really?

Answer (score 2):

In either case, the idea is to express the factor $3^{2y-x}$ as a product of a function of $y$ and a function of $x$, separately; i.e. $$3^{2y-x} = 3^{2y} 3^{-x},$$ therefore $$3^{2y} 3^{-x} = 9^{\pm x} 3^{2x-1},$$ or $$3^{2y} = 3^x 3^{\pm 2x} 3^{2x-1} = 3^{x \pm 2x + 2x - 1},$$ hence $$y = \frac{1}{2}(3x \pm 2x - 1).$$  Note I have used $\pm$ because you do not remember which version of the equation was written.  In the first case, we choose the negative sign and the result is $$y = \frac{x-1}{2}.$$  In the second case, we choose the positive sign and the result is $$y = \frac{5x-1}{2}.$$